# Is this space $l^2:=\{(x)_n\in\mathbb{R}^{\infty}:\sum^{\infty}_{i=1}|x_n|^2<\infty\}$ closed and bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology

The Lecturer demonstrate that $S:=\{(x_n)\in l^2:\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}|x_n|^2\leq 1\}\subset l^2$ is closed by showing every convergent sequence $(a_n)$ in $S$ has the limit $a^*\in S$.

Now I have a question :
Is this space itself $l^2:=\{(x)_n\in\mathbb{R}^{\infty}:\sum^{\infty}_{i=1}|x_n|^2<\infty\}$ closed and bounded?

I know this is unbounded because there is no $(b_n)\in\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ for all $(a_n)\in l^2 $such that $b_n\geq a_n$   for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. What about the closeness?

More specifically, regarding the definition of closedness: **Every convergent sequence converges to the limit within the space**, I have two interpretations that bother me.

**interpretation 1**

Suppose we have a sequence $(a_n)\in l^2$, and this sequence "looks like convergent(eventually to some point $x$)". If this $x$ in $l^2$, then we say $l^2$ is closed, otherwise is not closed. **Here, we could affirmative to say $l^2$ is not closed if $x\notin l^2$**

**interpretation 2**

Suppose we have a sequence $(a_n)\in l^2$, and this sequence "looks like convergent(eventually to some point $x$)" If this $x\notin l^2$, then $(a_n)$  is not a convergent sequence, the definition only says convergent sequence. **Here, we cannot affirmative to say $l^2$ is not closed if $x\notin l^2$.**

Now, you may see those two can draw different informations, **which interpretation is correct?**

Then, only given this set, asking if $l^2:=\{(x)_n\in\mathbb{R}^{\infty}:\sum^{\infty}_{i=1}|x_n|^2<\infty\}$ closed or not? Why ?

Please answer from a sequence perspective, haven't touched topology or finite sub-cover staff yet, just have arrived at sequential compact.

Thanks for any answers and comments.

---

The bounded set definition: Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. A set $A\subset X$ is called bounded if there exists $\bar{x}\in X$ and $R>0$ such that $A\subset B_R(\bar{x})$

---

Please don't downvote, you may help me out or clear up my confusion

Comment: What is your definition of a bounded set in $\ell^2$?

Comment: No normed linear space (other than $\{0\}$) is bounded. Any space is closed in itself.

Comment: @ArcticChar question edited.

Comment: @geetha290krm much appreciate if you may enlighten me through my question.

Comment: Your argument that $\ell^2$ is unbounded is wrong.

Comment: @ArcticChar would you please write me a correct one, thank you so much

Comment: You talk about  a set being closed or bounded **in a certain space**. Just asking if a set is closed or bounded has no meaning.

Comment: @geetha290krm That's a good point. what if respect o $R^{\infty}$ under Euclidean metric. Is it closed?

Comment: What do you mean by $R^{\infty}$ under the Euclidean metric?

Comment: @geetha290krm Is $l^2$ closed or not in $(\mathbb{R}^{\infty}, \|\cdot\|_2)$

Comment: What is the difference between $l^{2}$ and $(\mathbb R^{\infty},\|.\|_2)$? If you are trying to define $\|(a_n)\|_{\infty}$ for all real sequence that is not possible. You can define this norm only when $\sum |a_n|^{2}<\infty$, so $l^{2}$ and $(\mathbb R^{\infty},\|.\|_2)$ are one and the same.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thank you for your reply. Is that mean $l^2$ both open and closed? since it is the whole space

Comment: That is not very interesting ... any topological space is closed in itself.  Your lecturer demonstrated that $S$ is closed in $l^2$, which is interesting.